# tensorflow session run feed_dict - to zip or not to zip

Tags: tensorflow

what's the difference (in Tensorflow) between running session like this:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trainingDataX,Y: trainingDataY})
```

and like this:

```
for (x, y) in zip(trainingDataX, trainingDataY):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

EDIT:
of course I understand that zip takes items one by one ... 
but what's the difference from result point of view ? zip is used in plenty examples - but its obviously slower... is there any reason to use it?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are feeding the data in batch mode whereas in the second case you are feeding data one by one.

Comment: ok I wasn't clear enough in my question. of course your answer is right.. but what's the difference from result point of view ? zip is used in plenty examples - but its obviously slower... is there any reason to use it?

Comment: There are different variants of Gradient Descent optimizer. If you feed data one by one, batch gradient descent won't have the significance.

Comment: @MichaelZet -- if you understand this answer then it is a machine learning question not a TF question.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you are using the same learning rate in both examples then when using zip each sample will get a much bigger importance (also the outliers...)